# Filtering a formatted element in ListItem and sap.m.List

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm stuck in developing a filter for a list.
My list displays in the item an icon depending on two entries from the actual data record.

```
new sap.ui.core.Icon({
    src : {
        parts : [
            { path : "Model>date" },
            { path : "Model>inventory" }                                        
        ],
        formatter : function(date, inventory) {
                if (!inventory) {
                    return "sap-icon://decline";
                }
                if (date != "31.12.9999") {
                    return "sap-icon://decline";
                }
                return "sap-icon://accept";
        }
    }
})
```

Now i will implement a filter for this information:

- a) show all entries with the decline-icon
- b) show all entries with the accept-icon

My problem is that the filter is accepting only one path-element.

```
var dateFilter =new sap.ui.model.Filter({
    path : "date",
    test : function(date) {
        //pseudo code
        if(#filter-true)
            show entries with accept;
        else
            show entries with decline;
    }
});
aFilters.push(dateFilter)
```

But actual i've no idea for implementing this filter.
Can someone help me please?

PS: I know that my grammar is not the best ;)

Comment: It's better not to rely on UI-related things, like icons, while dealing with data model. Instead of that, add extra parameter to you data model, which would define a state of something and only then, filter based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple filters that rely on different paths.

```
var oDateFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
    path : "date",
    test : function(sDate) {
        if(sDate === "31.12.9999"){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

The code above creates a filter that operates using the "date" property of your model.

```
var oInventoryFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
    path : "inventory",
    test : function(bInventory) {
        if(bInventory !== true){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

The code above creates a filter using the "inventory" property. Now, we are combining it via the following code:

```
var oCombinedFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
    filters: [oDateFilter, oInventoryFilter],
    and: true
});
```

This filter returns true for all elements that got the inventory property set to true (make sure that the parameter is a boolean!) and the date set to "31.12.9999".

For more information see [sap.ui.model.Filter](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Filter/).